# Prove Eigen vectors of a Hermitian matrix form a non-singular matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I know that the Eigen vectors of a Hermitian matrix are orthogonal.

But i can't move from there. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for every matrix formed of eigenvectors.
Since eigenvectors corresponding to same or different eigenvalues are L.I.
In case of hermitian matrix we have $$A=PDP^{-1} $$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the $X_i$ are orthogonal with respect to the standard Hermitian inner product on $\Bbb C^n$, *viz*. $\langle V, W \rangle = \bar V \cdot W$; then:

Since, as the text of the problem states, the eigenvectors $X_i$ are orthogonal:

$\langle X_i, X_j \rangle = 0, \; i \ne j, \tag 1$

we can form the the matrix $C$ whose $k$-th column is $X_k$:

$C = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2 & \ldots & X_k & \ldots & X_n \end{bmatrix}, \tag 2$

and then form $C^\dagger$, the Hermitian adjoint of $E$, *whose rows are the complex conjugates of the columns of* $E$:

$C^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix} \bar X_1 \\ \bar X_2 \\ \vdots \\ \bar X_k \\ \vdots \\ \bar X_n \end{bmatrix}; \tag 3$

then it is easy to see that

$D = C^\dagger C = \begin{bmatrix} \langle X_i, X_j \rangle \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \delta_{ij} \Vert X_i \Vert^2 \end{bmatrix} \tag 4$

is a diagonal matrix whose $ii$ entry is $\Vert X_i \Vert^2 = \langle X_i, X_i \rangle \ne 0$.  Now $D$ is nonsingular, its inverse being

$D^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \delta_{ij} \Vert X_i \Vert^{-2} \end{bmatrix}; \tag 5$

it then follows that both $C$ and $C^\dagger$ are non-singular as well.